# iPhone: Creating another thread and do some processes

Tags: iphone, concurrency

I want to create a separate thread from main thread and do some processes there. For ex: When i'm going through my application screens (navigation controller, view controller etc.), i also want to have an another thread where-in some upload processes should be going on in the background.

How can i achieve this in iOS development? Please guide me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of options, too many to list exhaustively, but perhaps the easiest way to hatch just a single additional thread is [performSelectorInBackground:withObject:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground:withObject:), e.g.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomething:) withObject:nil];

- (void)doSomething:(id)object
{
    NSLog(@"I'm running on a separate thread!");
}
```

There's also [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:) for pushing things back to the main thread for UIKit and various other means of dispatching selectors to specific other threads.

You can directly talk to [NSThread](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/) if you want to adjust priorities or otherwise hatch threads in a more specific fashion. Be careful in either case because you won't have an autorelease pool in your background thread unless you create one yourself.

If you're planning to issue lots of threads, you'd probably pushing [NSInvocationOperations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/) to an [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/). Operation queues ensure that operations are distributed to background threads in an optimal fashion for the number of CPUs and cores your device has.

You should be completely sure you want a background thread though. As a general rule of thumb, if something is able to operate either synchronously or asynchronously, posting to the main thread, the latter is the more efficient way to proceed, especially in terms of battery life. The new blocks-based asynchronous methods are taking a lot of the spaghetti out of writing event driven code that's supposed to perform a simple linear action, so if you're okay sticking to iOS 4 and above then check those out.

Comment: Hello, Thank you. Which one i should use whether "detachNewThreadSelector" (or) "performSelectorInBackground". Please advise. And i want to know how does this thread creation works? Is it always(every interval) getting called this func and do the processes (or) we need to start thread everytime. How do i stop this thread running if i want?

Comment: I don't think it's going to make any odds — most likely one of them just calls the other. One call to detachNewThreadSelector or performSelectorInBackground will cause the nominated selector to be called just once.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet of code to get you started

```
    // start a new thread:
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(onNewThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

- (void) onNewThread{
    // do stuff on new thread
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you. Which one i should use whether "detachNewThreadSelector" (or) "performSelectorInBackground". Please advise. And i want to know how does this thread creation works? Is it always(every interval) getting called this func and do the processes (or) we need to start thread everytime. How do i stop this thread running if i want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 4.0+ I highly recommend using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and blocks.

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setCompletionBlock:^{
      // Use when fetching text data
      NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

      // Use when fetching binary data
      NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
   }];
   [request setFailedBlock:^{
      NSError *error = [request error];
   }];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

It's blindingly simple to use and runs all queries asynchronously (by default).

Comment: This is for network operations dude! He asked for creating threads for general taks.

Comment: I know it's for network operations. Re-read the question, the OP asked how to upload in the background. Which `ASIHTTPRequest` does.

Answer (score -2):

You can do that with NSOperation. Read up on it.